# React Native Android lag during animation

Tags: react-native

I experience the lag during transition animation when Navigator goes to below scene ShiftEdit. Animation starts immediately but it stops for a millisecond. InteractionManager is used to postpone rendering of four picker components. Every picker component has list of items that is built from an array. There is lots of items. Is it possible that this is calculated even when picker component isn't rendered yet in ShiftEdit and this is the reason of the lag? Could you help me please?

```
'use strict'
    import React, {View, Text, StyleSheet, InteractionManager, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';
    import { connect } from 'react-redux';
    import Spinner from 'react-native-spinkit';
    import StyleCommon from '../styles';
    import TimePicker from '../components/time-picker';
    import ColorPicker from '../components/color-picker';
    import LabelPicker from '../components/label-picker';


    class ShiftEdit extends React.Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
          isReady: false,
          shiftId: '',
          startHour: '',
          endHour: '',
          color: '',
        }
      }

      componentDidMount() {
        InteractionManager.runAfterInteractions(() => {
          this.setState({isReady: true});
        });
      }

      onChangeItem = (label, val) => {
        let data = {};
        data[label] = val;
        this.setState(data);
      }

      renderPlaceholder() {
         return (
           <View style={styles.container}>
             <Text>Loading...</Text>
           </View>
         )
       }

      render() {
        if (!this.state.isReady) {
          return this.renderPlaceholder();
        }

        return (
          <View style={{flex:1, flexDirection: 'column'}}>
            <TimePicker label={'Start hour'} value={this.state.startHour} onChange={this.onChangeItem.bind(this, 'startHour')} />
            <TimePicker label={'End hour'} value={this.state.endHour} onChange={this.onChangeItem.bind(this, 'endHour')} />
            <ColorPicker label={'Color'} value={this.state.color} onChange={this.onChangeItem.bind(this, 'color')} />
            <LabelPicker label={'Shift ID'} value={this.state.shiftId} onChange={this.onChangeItem.bind(this, 'shiftId')} />
          </View>
        )
      }
    };
```

I tried to control animation registration as Chris suggested but it still the same:

```
  onPress = () => {
    let handle = InteractionManager.createInteractionHandle();
    this.props.navigator.push({component: 'shiftedit'});
    InteractionManager.clearInteractionHandle(handle);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually this is the only solution that works for me now:

```
  componentDidMount() {
    // InteractionManager.runAfterInteractions(() => {
    //   this.setState({isReady: true});
    // })
    setTimeout(() => {
       this.setState({isReady: true});
    }, 75);
  }
```

but I'd rather use InteractionManager...

Comment: Instead of using InteractionManager in ShiftEdit, can you try using InteractionManager.runAfterInteractions inside the componentDidMount of each picker component? Let me know if that helps!

Comment: Hi, I already checked it, but it works the same, I use RN 0.22 maybe this is the case.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a wild guess as I've no experience with InteractionManager directly. But after looking over the [Interaction Manager Docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/interactionmanager.html) I noticed that there's a way to register animations. So, my guess is that the Navigator's animations haven't been properly registered. So maybe try something like this...

```
var handle = InteractionManager.createInteractionHandle();
// run your navigator.push() here... (`runAfterInteractions` tasks are queued)
// later, on animation completion:
InteractionManager.clearInteractionHandle(handle);
// queued tasks run if all handles were cleared
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Also, keep in mind that if you're running the **React Native Debugger** while testing your app, React Native animations will appear jittery on Android.

That's been my experience.

https://github.com/jhen0409/react-native-debugger